# Можно ли как-то присвоить значению флага значение из комбинаций других элементов enum?

Tags: c#

Можно ли как-то присвоить значению флага значение из комбинаций других элементов enum?

Что-то в духе такого:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyTypeObject
{
    Unit = Defender | Worker,
    Defender,
    Worker
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Располагайте ваши значения по степеням двойки: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16... и затем используйте выражения в конце определения.

```
[Flags]
public enum MyTypeObject
{
    Defender = 1,
    Worker = 2,
    Unit = Defender | Worker,
}
```

По необходимости используйте [Enum.HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx).

См. также: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19582477/5752652

Comment: 0 — не степень двойки, 0 не надо использовать как флаг, 0 — это только когда все флаги сняты

Comment: @АндрейNOP Действвительно, зря правил ответ. Спасибо за улучшение ответа!

Comment: Я обычно на 0 назначаю Empty или None.